# Should all lambda declarations be const static?

Tags: c++

Lambda object declarations (`std::function<>()` / `auto lambda = []()...`) are always literals, right? So does that mean we should, for clarity, coding etiquette and even performance, always declare them `const static` just like any other scoped literal constant?

Comment: Their operators are `const`-qualified by default anyway. But `static` often won't work that well when capturing things like local variables and the like.

Comment: And last but not least a lambda object doesn't have anything to do with `std::function` and if you care at least the smallest bit about performance, you won't put a lambda into a `std::function` if not neccessary, anyway.

Comment: No other litreal can *capture* objects.

Comment: @ChristianRau why is storing a lambda in a std::function bad?

Comment: @ausairman Because a `std::function` incurs some overhead (simply said it uses virtual functions and runtime polymorphism under the hood, not to speak about the missed inlining opportunities). Often you need a `std::function` for storing a lambda, i.e. when returning it from a function or when using it as member variable, but other times you don't (like as a local variable). And when you don't then `auto lambda = [...](...){...};` means much less overhead than putting it into a `std::function`.

Comment: @ChristianRau ok I didn't know that. What are your thoughts then on the same question for auto const static lambda = ...?

Comment: @ausairman Like said, there are many sitations where `static` won't work (capturing locals). But when it does, it might indeed be preferrable. And the `const`, well, never considered that, but might very well be an idea (of course only if one doesn't need a `mutable` lambda).

Comment: The standard defines in 2.14 what kinds of literals C++ has. Lambdas don't seem to be included in the list. Disclaimer: I only have the FDIS.

Comment: If you are using captures (like [&]), the lambda's functionality might depend on the value of the captured variables (which can change at run-time), so making them const-static wouldn't work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Lambda object declarations (std::function<>() / auto lambda = ...) are always literals, right?

No, lambdas are not literals. They can capture state from the enclosing scope and that can be non-const. Consider:

```
int f(int a, int b) {
   auto lambda = [=](int x) { return a*x; };
   return lambda(b);
}
```

If you add `static` there, the *variable* `lambda` will be shared by all the code that uses `f`, and it will only be initialized on the first call capturing the value of `a` from the first call to `f`. By not having it `static` each call to `f` will use it's own first argument.

While the example is very artificial, I hope it helps to clear the point.

Comment: Wouldn't adding const in your sample be considered a Good Thing? It's maybe overkill for such a small function, yet getting the habit of writing it whenever possible seems right.

Comment: Are you missing a `=` in there or is the `a` captured automatically?

Comment: @stijn: What could you change in the lambda? I don't think there is any reason to add an unneeded `const`. By default the generated `operator()` is marked as `const` so the extra qualification won't make any difference and does not add information. For the lambda to modify it's own state it needs to be marked as `mutable`, which is quite explicit already. I don't see the `const` adding any value in this case, and it is going to be awkward, like people that do `const int f();` (you might be one of them :))

Comment: @ChristianRau: `a` will be captured implicitly by value.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas But I thought only if the capture-all (`=`) is present. But I might just have been wrong.